# Format ruby time instance as 2014-09-19T15:40:24Z

Tags: ruby, iso8601

If I have a ruby time instance, how can I format it so that it can be formatted into the following:

```
2014-09-19T15:40:24Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
require 'time'
Time.now.utc.iso8601
# => "2015-04-26T20:51:06Z"
```

You can convert also back from a string in `iso8601` format to a time instance:

```
Time.iso8601("2015-04-26T20:51:06Z")
# => 2015-04-26 20:51:06 UTC
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for `Time#iso8601`. You may need to run `.utc` first if you don't want a timezone at the end.